# Restore disk image to a bigger disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted, dd

I've created an image from my ssd (as I switched around Linux and Windows usage on the disks).

Right now I want to restore the whole SSD(128Gb) image to my HDD(1TB), but I'm concerned about using dd as I have a "data" partition on the end of the HDD. I don't want the "data" partition to be messed around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So don't use `dd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, as I wasn't sure about running it with dd

I used 
`partx -a -v file.iso` as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/211338/how-to-mount-a-multi-partition-disk-image-in-linux)
to mount the image's partitions

After that, I started gparted using the terminal:

```
gparted /dev/loop* /dev/sda
```

Where **loop** is the mounted image and **/dev/sda** the drive I wanted to work with